# Daylight Time Zone conversion in C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, timezone

How to check whether a particular time zone falls under "DAYLIGHTTIMEZONE" or not using C# asp.net?

If the time zone falls under "DAYLIGHTTIMEZONE" should i be changing the time into standard time zone?

I will get the time zone(Time Zones Listed in Windows OS) as input from user and store it in database,whenever the user logs in i will display the time and date based on the timezone selected by the user.Now what role does daylightsaving play here? Whether any changes should be made if the particular timezone falls under "DaylightsavingZone".

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.aspx

Comment: @Soner: Only if the OP really needs answers from people who care more about reputation than about helping people. The question is reasonably well written, which is enough for me...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`TimeZoneInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx) class introduced in .NET 3.5.

It's not clear what your bigger goal is, but basically `TimeZoneInfo` *should* cover whatever you're trying to do, such as converting from one time zone to another. It's not always the simplest class to use correctly, partly because the [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) type is badly designed to start with, unfortunately :(

I'm working (occasionally!) on a new date and time library for .NET called [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com), but unfortunately that's not ready yet :(

EDIT: Okay, so your steps should be:

- Work out how to get the time zone from the user in an appropriate form for `TimeZoneInfo`. You'll want to end up storing the [`Id`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.id.aspx) in the database.
- When you want to display a time:

  - Fetch the time zone using [`FindSystemTimeZoneById`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.findsystemtimezonebyid.aspx)
  - Get the current time using [`DateTimeOffset.UtcNow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.utcnow.aspx)
  - Call [`TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396765.aspx) to convert to the target time zone
  - Format the result appropriately for the user

Comment: @Jon Two sad smilies in one answer? Sounds like someone needs a hug.

Comment: Thanks a lot Skeet...I have one more doubt on whether the same above mentioned steps can be followed even if the particular timezone falls under "DAYLIGHT TIMEZONE"?

Comment: @Pranesh: TimeZoneInfo sorts all of that for you.

Comment: Skeet consider this scenario: A particular time zone falls under "DAYLIGHT SAVING TIMEZONE" for ex:Pacific Standard Time so will the timezoneinfo.converttime method automatically generate the final output based on the "DAYLIGHT SAVING TIME" or else should i process the daylight time difference manually?

Comment: @Pranesh: As I *keep* saying: it does all that for you. Just try it! (I'm not sure why you keep putting daylight saving time in all-caps and quoting it, by the way...)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for  [**TimeZone.IsDaylightSavingTime**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1f14e97.aspx)

Comment: Not without a lot of extra effort - as otherwise that will represent the *server's* time zone. TimeZone is effectively deprecated in favour of TimeZoneInfo.

Comment: @Jon Why the down vote .... i am checking this out on 2.0 ...got anything better at this version ?